# JQuery Get String From <img class="www.example.com">

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

This should be a tweak for the jQuery based image gallery "Galleria". You can click on a thumbnail div called images and it brings you on the site based on the url in the class of the a tag.

Pseudo Code HTML

```
<div id="galleria">
    <div class="images"><a class="www.google.com" href="bens_img/1.jpg"><img src="bens_img/thumb1.jpg"></a>
    <div class="images"><a class="www.yahoo.com" href="bens_img/2.jpg"><img src="bens_img/thumb2.jpg"></a>
    <div class="images"><a class="www.tokyo.co.jp" href="bens_img/3.jpg"><img src="bens_img/thumb3.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Pseudo JQuery (JavaScript)

```
Get Value from class of <a>
Onclick ".images".this
href to Value from class of <a>
```

Comment: just FYI, using a class element for data value is conceptually wrong.

Comment: At the very least, use an HTML5 `data-` attribute instead, such as `data-external-link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i've understood correctly,

```
$('galleria.images').click(function(){
   window.location.href = $("a", this).attr('class');
});

//although i wonder why you'd put href's within a class attribute. hmmm..
```

Do take a look at this SO post on [valid characters for CSS classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names).

Comment: Thats because the "Galleria" interpreted it like this.

Comment: @Freeman: but this makes me vary. what if there are invalid characters(for HTML classes) but otherwise valid url?..

Comment: I would question using a plugin that renders a URL to an anchor class.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, is there any reason why the URL is in the class of the anchor?  You have the image path in the href (normally reserved for the destination URL), and then you have a nested img tag with the same reference.  Wouldn't your code look more like this?

```
    <div class="images"><a href="www.google.com"><img src="bens_img/thumb1.jpg"></a></div>
```

Comment: Galleria usully interprete it like this: <div class="images"><a href="THEBIGPICTURE.jpg"><img src="THETHUMBNAIL.jpg"></a> - And I need a tweak, when you click on the div (which contains the thumnail.jpg) then you where href'ed to another webpage.

Comment: did you add the class="www.google.com" then? Or was it the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in the `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` should fix it.

```
$('#galleria div.images a').each(function(){
   $(this).attr("href", "http://" + $(this).attr('class'));
});
```

You're missing closing `</div>` tags on each of the `<div class="images">` too BTW.

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Ku6Pc/ is an example to show it working.